# Bodies rolling on an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

So I set up an inclined plane (of cardboard) 10 degrees from the horizontal. I then derived an equation from Newton's Laws of Motion about the displacement along the plane of the objects.  The equation I derived for the velocity is $\sqrt{2xg\sin\left(10\right)}$. Where x is the displacement along the inclined plane. This equation doesn't take friction into account though, so when I derived the equation while taking friction into account the velocity is slightly less. That equation is $v\ =\ 9.8t\left(\sin\left(10\right)-k\cos\left(10\right)\right)$. v is velocity, t is time and k is the coefficient of friction. The equations do not have a mass term in them, so they are identical, which must mean that the displacement of the two objects is the same at any instant in time. I then rolled an object with a mass of 103 grams and an object with a mass of 40 grams on the plane. But the object of mass 40 grams turns out to have a larger acceleration than the other object. So what went wrong?

Comment: Respect for setting up a real experiment instead of endlessly spinning equations around.

Comment: If you tilt the plane up to a higher angle like above 60°, use blocks that slide instead of roll, and make sure the surfaces are as smooth as possible, you might get better agreement

Comment: @RC_23 this is correct. The equations above are for a sliding object. If two objects with different masses but identical sliding friction coefficients were slid down an incline, they would slide at the same rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because you forgot to account for the rotation of the object as it rolls down the incline. Even two objects with the same mass can roll down an inclined plane at different accelerations if they have different moments of inertia (for example, a solid cylinder and a hollow cylinder).

See [this text](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/11-1-rolling-motion) for a derivation of the formula. Rolling down an inclined plane is example 11.1.

---

Edit:

Looking at your equations, you derived the formula for the motion of a mass *sliding* down an inclined plane, not rolling. If you want to test a sliding object, you can use blocks: first a block by itself, then a block with a significant mass on top of it. Alternatively you can measure the moments of inertia of your objects and then use the formula derived in the link above.

[Here's a gif of a race between objects of identical masses and radii rolling down an incline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rolling_Racers_-_Moment_of_inertia.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your equations? I was just curious.
Jacob Stuligross's reply makes sense to me. I was picturing the standard solid spheres you find in textbooks. However, as he pointed out, the shape of the object could determine their respective accelerations.

Dissipated energy could be another consideration. What were the surface areas of the objects? Intuitively, I at least would generally forget about air drag (especially for a 10 degee inclination, which I would associate with a relatively low final velocity).

It should be possible to calculate its rough value to compare it with the P.E. of the mass to see if it should be factored in.

The mass loses P.E. in a mass dependant way. That P.E. is lost as dissipated energy and gained as K.E (which also is mass dependant). The D.E. however should be surface area dependant?
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/airfri.html

If you discount dissipation, you would have a velocity of $\sqrt{2 g h}$, where $h$ is 'height' and is your plane's height.

I am guessing you calculated acceleration as: $\frac{\sqrt{2 g h}}{t}$, where $t$ is time, with the initial velocities of both being $0$.

If you recalculated the velocity with a drag force (maybe roughly air $R A v$ where $R$ is resistance, $A$ is surface area and $v$ is velocity?) thrown in, maybe you get more exact values? Though I am not sure what the equation would be then for calculating the energy dissipated and simply finding $v$ as the solution of:
$m g h = \frac{1}{2} m v^{2} + F_{drag} \left( v \right)$

I am using the most elementary physics I can recollect here. Forgive me if I grossly oversimplified it. It was not clear to me whether you were describing a high school physics experiment or something more sophisticated. In the latter case, this would be too elementary an analysis.

Comment: Thanks ZaellixA :)! Appreciate the edit. I should use MathJax.

Comment: I was just wondering whether or not Newton's Laws of Motion predicted reality. To test this, I just put up this experiment at home to see if it works. I have also posted my equations above. And no, your answer was not too elementary for me!

Comment: Thanks! I am guessing Jacob's answer covers it then.